# Extracting value contained in PointerType

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

LLVM IR

```
  call void @llvm.dbg.declare(metadata i32* %z, metadata !24, metadata !DIExpression()), !dbg !25
  %arraydecay1 = getelementptr inbounds [55 x i8], [55 x i8]* %input, i32 0, i32 0, !dbg !26
  %call2 = call i64 @strlen(i8* %arraydecay1) #4, !dbg !28
```

strlen doc https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/

%call2 is the return value of strlen function which is of size_t type. I thought its a struct type but it turned out to be a pointer type, which is of type i64 (i8*)*

How do i de-reference and get the integer value contained in the pointer value.

Edit: I was using wrong operand but the problem is not solved yet. Its not about pointer type, int 64 type conversion that i have issues. See below

```
 CallInst I; //passed by reference
  CallSite cs(&I);
  if(!cs.getInstruction()){
    return;
  } else {
    for (User* user : cs.getInstruction()->users()) {
      if (Instruction* i = dyn_cast<Instruction>(user)) {
        Value *v1 = dyn_cast<Value>(i->getOperand(0));
        errs() << "Type:==" << *(v1) << "\n";
        errs() << "is integer type=" << (v1->getType()->isIntegerTy()) << "\n";
        ConstantInt *cint = dyn_cast<ConstantInt>(v1);
        if (cint) {
          errs() << "constant int" << *cint << "\n";
        } else {
          errs() << "not a constant int??" << "\n";
        }
      }
    }
  }

Type:==  %call2 = call i64 @strlen(i8* %arraydecay1) #4, !dbg !28
is integer type=1
not a constant int??
```

Comment: If you have the pointer *value*, you get the value being pointed to using a `LoadInst`. If all you have is the pointer `type`, you cannot ge the value. On LLVM versions up to 9 you can get the `type` pointed to by calling PointerType::getElementType().

Comment: getElementType returns  i64 (i8*)*, how do i de-reference?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about `%call2`, the return value of `strlen` call, then its type is `i64` as it is written in `call i64 @strlen(...)`.

The `i64 (i8*)*` type is a pointer to a function that accepts `i8*` and returns `i64`. It corresponds to the type of `&strlen` expression in C.

So, if you want to work with the return value of `strlen`, then just use `%call2` value.

Comment: I am using %call2 value but dont know how to dereference the pointer. As you can see i grabbed PointerType's is getElementType returns i64 (i8*)*

Comment: Like I said, the type in question is `i64`. It is a integer type, but the whole value is not a constant. I see nothing related to ` i64 (i8*)*`.

Comment: My goal was grabbing %call2 but it appears i was iterating RHS side of the instruction (called function params and its return value spec). I resolved it by iterating CallInst instruction rather than using CallSite. For pointertype, it appears more work is needed. I will update this question with answers for both cases. Bottom line, since LLVM is SSA CallInst has both the spec (create and invoke) and the return value can be obtained by iterating the CallInst instruction. I got blind folded by going in CallSite direction